# Is there anyway to reformat a python script?

Tags: python

Below I have a python script that won't work if I create a `.py` file and paste the following code inside it

```
import os\r\nimport time \r\nimport random \r\n \r\ndef fun_9991():\r\n    ## a simple code example to test \r\n    for i in range (0 , 10 ):\r\n        print ( " loop count {} , random number is {} , time is {} ".format(i , random.randrange(10) , int(time.time()/1000)))\r\n    print ("loop reached the end")\r\n    \r\n \r\nif __name__ == "__main__":\r\n    fun_9991()\r\n\r\n\r\n
```

My goal is to convert the above script to its original form below without having to edit it myself

I tried using `replace()` to remove `\r\n` but I was not successful

```
import os
import time 
import random 
 
def fun_9991():
    ## a simple code example to test 
    for i in range (0 , 10 ):
        print ( " loop count {} , random number is {} , time is {} ".format(i , random.randrange(10) , int(time.time()/1000)))
    print ("loop reached the end")
    
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    fun_9991()
```

Comment: Does your original code contain ``\r\n`` as the *two* characters "carriage return" and "newline", or the *four* characters ``\``, ``r``, ``\``, ``n``? Can you perhaps provide a shorter sample, such as ``import sys\r\nprint(sys.version_info)\r\n``? How do you apply ``replace8)``? What do you mean by ``I was not successful`` – did you get an error, did nothing happen, did something unexpected happen?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi  after running the script I get the same code unchanged

Comment: After running *what* script? You do not show any script using ``replace()``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just write the string out to a file it should somewhat work:

```
with open('example.py', 'w') as text_file:
    text_file.write("""import os\r\nimport time \r\nimport random \r\n \r\ndef fun_9991(): \r\n  # a simple code example to test \r\n    for i in range (0 , 10 ):\r\n        print ( " loop count {} , random number is {} , time is {} ".format(i , random.randrange(10) , int(time.time()/1000)))\r\n    print ("loop reached the end")\r\n    \r\n \r\nif __name__ == "__main__":\r\n    fun_9991()\r\n\r\n\r\n""")
```

You can also just execute the code if you want as well:

```
exec("""import os\r\nimport time \r\nimport random \r\n \r\ndef fun_9991(): \r\n  # a simple code example to test \r\n    for i in range (0 , 10 ):\r\n        print ( " loop count {} , random number is {} , time is {} ".format(i , random.randrange(10) , int(time.time()/1000)))\r\n    print ("loop reached the end")\r\n    \r\n \r\nif __name__ == "__main__":\r\n    fun_9991()\r\n\r\n\r\n""")
```

Comment: Since you said in the other answers comment that you don't have python installed, use the second example with exec as you won't need to generate a .py file

Comment: I tried the second option using an online compiler tutorialspoint to be specific but throws a syntax error

Comment: The online compiler might not accept exec tbf. I'm not sure what you can do in that case, I'd suggest you install python at that stage.

Comment: using windows cmd I can run the code with `exec()`, but if I create a simple script that has the script declared as a string variable I get a `SyntaxError: Unexpected character after line continuation character `

Comment: That's odd, if I put that exact line in a .py file and run it it gives me the desired output and no errors

Comment: I don't want to create a file because I will be generating lots of random scripts some of them are really big

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know how to do it without installing python, but you could try posting another question with clear statements of what exactly you want and how you want to achieve it. Best of luck to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can just write the exact text you have to a file.

```
with open('test.py', 'w') as file:
    file.write(test)
```

[image]

Comment: I don't have python installed on the system that I will be running the code on I want to use `runpy`

Comment: @m3sfit How are you expecting to use `Python` to create this file, if you do not have it installed?

Comment: using another compiled python script that has a function that uses runpy